# Clustering in Weka

Tags: cluster-analysis, weka, k-means, pca

I have some data collected using an online survey. Therefore, there are no classes/labels in the data to evaluate clustering results. I am trying to do the clustering in order to cluster participants in some groups for another task.

In the data, I have 10 attributes like: `Age`, `Gender`, etc., and 111 examples or data-points.
It's my first time to perform clustering and it's been difficult to find potential clusters in the data.

Here are the steps I have performed in Weka:

1. I have tried to cluster the data using all attributes, all types of clustering in Weka (like cobweb, EM .. etc)  and using different cluster numbers (1-10). And When I visualise the clusters, they don't make any sense and the data are widely spread between x and y axis.
2. I have applied PCA and selected different number of attribute combinations according to the ranks obtained in PCA. The best clustering result was obtained using k-means and with only 2 combinations of attributes and the number of clusters selected was 3, and seed was 7 (sorry, I have no idea what the seed is).
   [image: Here is the visual result]

My Questions:

1. Are the steps I performed to cluster data correct? If not please give me advice/s
2. Is this considered as a good clustering result?
3. How can I optimise or enhance my clusters?
4. What is meant with seed in Weka clustering?

Comment: The seed is the random number seed. Starting with a different random place is likely to give slightly different results, particularly if there are no strong clusters present.  If your results vary a lot depending on the random seed, this is a bad sign.

Comment: If you are clustering demographics like age and gender, you wouldn't necessarily expect to find strong clusters. The age distribution in the population is fairly uniform between newborns and old people, and there are a roughly equal number of men and women at those ages.

Comment: Thank you Zbicyclist. The was a very slight change when I changed the seed. In regard to the age I am selecting participants who are aged (18-50), Would I expect strong clusters with this group of age? In general, are the steps performed correct or at least acceptable? What do you think about the clusters I got in the plot, are they strong, week or ok? Kind regards, Shosho